# AWS code commit https connection via browser

Tags: git, amazon-web-services

I"ve created a repository in code commit of AWS and now I'm trying to connect to the HTTPS link that is provided but it displays the message :

> Invalid request

I've added the policy `AWSCodeCommitFullAccess` to my user policy.

So can I actually connect to the repo via the browser ?

Comment: By connect means you want to just put the URL of the code commit repo in the browser and connect to it?

Comment: @error2007s yeah kinda like on git hub, maybe it's not how it works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Code commit URLs are not suppose to handle HTTPS request coming from a browser. Please follow this AWS developers guide for options to connect to AWS Code Commit Repository.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-connect.html

Answer (score 1):

Actually its possible, To access AWS Git via Browser follow like below

https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/codesuite/codecommit/repositories/
Or
https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/codesuite/codecommit/repositories/REPOSITORYNAME/setup

in the URL:

1. change the us-east-1 based on your region.
2. change the REPOSITORYNAME with your exact repo name.

Thanks